# I am a free will baptist ordained minister, and I want to join a baptist church, do I need to be ordained again?

Tags: baptist, membership, ordination

I am a free will gospel Minister, if I join a Baptist church, do I have to ordained again?

Comment: You mean, I assume, "do I have to be ordained in order to hold a position equivalent to what I was previously qualified for?"

Comment: There's no way to answer this in general, you'll have to ask the church you want to join.

Comment: @curiousdannii What church requires people to be ordained before they can join? :D

Comment: @Jacob Depends on what type of "joining" you're talking about - if you're talking about joining the denomination rather than a local church then there would be many which require their ministers to be ordained. But this is just proving the question can't be definitively answered.

Comment: @Norman You may need to add "in order to serve as a minister" to the end of your question, if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

No, joining a Baptist church does not require ordination of any sort. It would make for a strange church where only ordained people were permitted membership.

Comment: I took the question as asking about joining a denomination as a minister, not just a regular church member.

Comment: @curiosdannii,that would be a good question... A much better question, in fact. But it's not the one that was asked, so it's not the one I answered.

Comment: Depends on whether the OP meant 'denomination' or 'congregation' with the word 'church'. I can definitely see how it would be understood your way, but I think the other way is also possible. I think it's both unclear and too broad so I voted to close it...

Comment: @curiousdannii: Why do I get the feeling you're arguing just for the sake of it?

Comment: I'm not, but the question has been closed and we asked the OP to explain more so no more arguing from me.